# Failed review - too subjective of a question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was stopped by this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5018614

I feel that the original question is asking for way too much opinion.

Comment: Are you asking if others agree that it should be closed?  Or asking about the validity of the audit itself?

Comment: @psubsee2003 both.

Comment: Then go to the question, cast your vote, and move on.  Personally I'd say it's Too Broad, not opinion based, but I can see either.

Comment: is there a black list for audits?

Comment: @DanielA.White No, there's a whitelist.  Audits are pulled from posts with no downvotes, close votes, or flags (among other criteria).  Applying any of those actions makes it invalid as an audit.

Comment: It's a bit broad, but a fairly good question with a decent answer.